# Filemaker Convert DD MM SS TO DD.DDD

Tags: latitude-longitude, filemaker

I am trying to convert the following fields:

```
LAT SS
LAT MM
LAT DD
```

to `LATITUDE DD.DDD`

```
LONG SS
LONG MM
LONG DD
```

to `LONGITUDE DD.DDD`

I've tried with a script but with NO resolve.

```
Dumped Vehicle::LATITUDE=(Dumped Vehicle::LAT SS/3600)+(Dumped Vehicle::LAT MM/60)+Dumped Vehicle::LAT DD
```

What am I doing wrong?

My idea was the user would enter the `DD MM SS` and the script would calculate during the entry of any of the fields upon exit or save of each field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a script for this - only calculation fields.

The basic formula to convert latitude or longitude given as degrees, minutes and seconds to decimal degrees is:

`degrees + minutes / 60 + seconds / 3600`

However, to determine the sign of the result, you also need to know the direction: North or South for the latitude, East or West for the longitude. I don't see that you have a field for that.

Comment: Thank you I only needed to know about the calculation fields. I used the following code:  Longitude=(LONG SS/3600)+(LONG MM/60)+LONG DD & Latitude=(LAT SS/3600)+(LAT MM/60)+LAT DD

Comment: I hope your code does not include the  `Longitude=` part, otherwise it will not work as expected. And the parentheses are entirely redundant (look up *PEMDAS*). And you haven't addressed the sign problem.